# git diff two repositories, get results from .git dir?

Tags: git, diff

I have two versions of a git repo on my computer, I wanted to know which is the differences between them, so I can know whether I should pull or not from the other repo.

I did a "git diff amslib ../workspace/amslib" and instead of showing me the differences between just the committed files in both repositories, it started to give me the differences in the .git directory too.

I suppose I'm not using the commands right, can anyone tell me how I should do it? I just want to know which version of the code has what changes, so I can either merge them, pull them, or manually copy them because I want some changes, but not others.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add one respository as a "remote" to the other, fetch the extra commits and then diff them against the current repo.

Comment: or add as alternate object store and add as remote

Comment: yeah that would work, I could add a remote and then diff the local master against the remote master.  good idea!

Answer (score 0):

You could do an ordinary recursive `diff` and ignore any results from the `.git` directories.  I suspect @Noufal's solution is cleaner, but this is an alternative.